# Bootstrap 2.3.2 side content not responding properly to small screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Initial view is like this. No problem here. 
[image]
But when it responds to small screens it changes to [image]

Why the images of right side in single column, they should be in a row until the device width is too small.

The Code I am using is

```
<div class="container-fluid">  
    <div class="row-fluid">  
    <div class="span8 border1"><img src="/bootstrap/img/a.jpg" /></div>  
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="row-fluid" >
            <div class="span5 border1"><img src="/bootstrap/img/b.jpg" /></div>  
            <div class="span5 border1"><img src="/bootstrap/img/b.jpg" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/kravigupta/bu43g/2/
What wrong I am doing here?

Edit: I could not get a good answer here. Had to manage it myself. I checked that for screen width less than 700px it gives 100% to all spanX class which is not desirable here. So, I added more rules for smaller screens.

```
@media (max-width: 320px){ ... }
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 730px) { ... }
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get a good answer here. Had to manage it myself. I checked that for screen width less than 700px it gives 100% to all spanX class which is not desirable here. So, I added more rules for smaller screens.

```
@media (max-width: 320px){ ... }
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 730px) { ... }
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, this (example 2) is how it is supposed to behave if you nest a row-fluid within a row-fluid. See [this link under Fluid Nesting](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html).

Comment: Try nesting the whole thing under a row fluid, and each image in a spanN class.

Comment: Sorry, but i could not understand. Can you please check this http://jsfiddle.net/kravigupta/bu43g/2/